# SQL Performance of Min/Max dates based on subset of measurements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a SQL query that returns all "Measurement Groups" along with the first and last dates that measurements within it were seen. These are derived from the child "Measurement" table, however within this specific query I only want to use the last 100 measurements (this will become user configurable) for the first/last date calculations. My attached query returns the correct results, however as the data set grows (millions of rows in the Measurements table), the performance becomes terrible, taking ~1min to return.

Hopefully you get the gist of what I am doing, Are there any ideas how can I improve the performance of this query?

**Query**

```sql
SELECT  mg.MeasurementGroupId,
        mg.[Name],
(
    SELECT  MIN(m1.MeasurementDateTime)
    FROM    dbo.Measurement m1
    WHERE   m1.MeasurementId IN
    (
        SELECT TOP 100 m2.MeasurementId
        FROM    dbo.Measurement m2
        WHERE   m2.MeasurementGroupId = mg.MeasurementGroupId
        ORDER
            BY  m2.MeasurementDateTime DESC
    )
) AS FirstMeasurement,
(
    SELECT  MAX(m1.MeasurementDateTime)
    FROM    dbo.Measurement m1
    WHERE   m1.MeasurementId IN
    (
        SELECT TOP 100 m2.MeasurementId
        FROM    dbo.Measurement m2
        WHERE   m2.MeasurementGroupId = mg.MeasurementGroupId
        ORDER
            BY  m2.MeasurementDateTime DESC
    )
) AS LastMeasurement
FROM    dbo.MeasurementGroup mg
```

**DDL**

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MeasurementGroup](
    [MeasurementGroupId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MeasurementGroup] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MeasurementGroupId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Measurement](
    [MeasurementId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MeasurementGroupId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MeasurementDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Value1] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Value2] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Value3] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Measurement] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MeasurementId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Measurement]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Measurement_MeasurementGroup] FOREIGN KEY([MeasurementGroupId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[MeasurementGroup] ([MeasurementGroupId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Measurement] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Measurement_MeasurementGroup]
GO
```

**DML**

```sql
WITH
  L0   AS (SELECT c FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS D(c)), -- 2^1
  L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),       -- 2^2
  L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),       -- 2^4
  Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS k FROM L2)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[MeasurementGroup] ([Name])
SELECT  'Measurement ' + CAST(k AS VARCHAR)
FROM    Nums
WHERE   k <= 10
```

```sql
WITH
  L0   AS (SELECT c FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS D(c)), -- 2^1
  L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),       -- 2^2
  L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),       -- 2^4
  L3   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),       -- 2^8
  L4   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),       -- 2^16
  L5   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),       -- 2^32
  Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS k FROM L5)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Measurement] ([MeasurementGroupId], [MeasurementDateTime], [Value1], [Value2], [Value3])
SELECT  mg.MeasurementGroupId, DATEADD(MINUTE, k, GETDATE()), 13.3, NULL, NULL
FROM    Nums n
CROSS JOIN  dbo.MeasurementGroup mg
WHERE   k < 1000000
```

Execution plan generated: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1zs_JIWH

Comment: It's great that you've provided us with DML and DDL, which is so useful to us. It'll really help as well if you show us the final result set your after here, for the sample data you provided; then we know the final goal.

Comment: The output isn't really the issue, it is more the performance. When the Measurements table is filled with millions of rows (can't write that many INSERT statements :o) it takes an age. If i remove the Min/max columns, it returns instantaneously. Wondering if there is a better way to structure the query using CTEs, JOINs, APPLYs?

Comment: So this is actually a performance question? Then we need the full DDL for any objects involved, **including** their relevant indexes, and the query plan (which you can provide using [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)). If this is a performance based question then you'll likely be rewriting your entire question I'm afraid; as performance questions are completely different to "why isn't the code working?" questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `apply`.  At the very least, you only need to fetch the 100 measurement rows once, rather than twice:

```
select mg.*, m.*
from dbo.MeasurementGroup mg cross apply
     (select min(MeasurementDateTime) as firstMeasurement,
             max(MeasurementDateTime) as lastMeasurement
      from (select top (100) m.*
            from measurement m
            where m.MeasurementGroupId = mg.MeasurementGroupId
            order by m.MeasurementDateTime desc
           ) m
     ) m;
```

This should be able to take an advantage of an index on `measurement(MeasurementGroupId, MeasurementDateTime desc)`.

Comment: Thank you. This coupled with an additional index sorted it right out for me :)